# Сделать 2 списка с одинаковыми элементами независимыми друг от друга

Tags: python, list

Есть 2 списка, вот как они создаются:

```
l1 = l2 = [2, 5, 6]
```

Но если удалить элемент из одного списка, то он удалится и из другого

```
del l2[1]
print(l1) # [2, 6]
```

Как сделать чтобы эти списки не зависели друг от друга, чтобы при удалении элемента из одного, этот элемент не удалялся из другого, **но запись инициализации осталась однострочной и сам литерал списка не пришлось дублировать**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать два списка с одинаковыми элементами, но независимыми друг от друга, вам необходимо скопировать элементы из одного списка в другой. Это можно сделать с помощью оператора = или метода copy().

Например:

```
# создаем первый список с элементами 1, 2, 3
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

# создаем второй список с элементами 1, 2, 3
# копируем элементы из первого списка
list2 = list1.copy()

# изменяем элемент в первом списке
list1[0] = 10

# выводим оба списка
print(list1) # [10, 2, 3]
print(list2) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: А в одну строчку прям никак? :(

Comment: @harpCS В одну строку - только если дублировать список: `l1, l2 = [2, 5, 6], [2, 5, 6]`